Duality Results for Convex SDP Programming
Suppose we have an SDP program with a convex (but nonlinear) objective $f(X)$, where $X$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. All other constraints are linear. Does there exist a dual program for such a convex SDP program? If so, is there any duality theory proven for such problems?
For example, suppose we have
\begin{array}{lll}
  \mbox{maximize} & A \cdot [X]^k & \\
  \mbox{subject to} 
    & (e_i e_i^T) \cdot X = 1 & \forall i = {1, ..., n}\\
    & X \succeq 0\\
  \end{array}
where $[X]^k$ denotes the element-wise k-th power of matrix X and k is even. How would the dual program of this problem be formulated, and can we prove any duality theories?

Edit: Using Slater's condition, I think this problem attains strong duality. I am still wondering whether there exists a clean way of formulating its dual program. Formulating the lagrangian dual using the smallest eigenvalue is very unclean and the Lagrangian function could not be taken derivative.
